# javascript: What is the purpose of window.self property?

Tags: javascript

As I understand `window == window.self == self`
What can be the reason / advantage to use `self` instead of `window` ?

Update. I think if i will understand logic of creators of above fields i will became more smart. 
Question is not What is the difference? 
Question is What was the purpose?

Comment: FYI, it has nothing in particular to do with JavaScript: http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#window

Answer (score 3):

They are equal, there is no advantage or disadvantage to using one over another unless you have style guidelines that specify which to prefer.